# Null Pointer Exception in Android using List

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent

I have following activities to load products from backend. Its a online food ordering with integration of paypal. I tried it in another app its working fine.

> I am getting Error on onCreate Method.

There are three activities Item list , Product  and product list adapter. I am getting error while loading view.  When i commented the lines of adapter its not crashing but after adding the adapters its crashing . Its driving me crazy.

---

```
import com.flavorbaba.AppController;
import com.flavorbaba.Config;
import com.flavorbaba.Product;
import com.flavorbaba.ProductListAdapter;
import com.flavorbaba.ProductListAdapter.ProductListAdapterListener;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.DefaultRetryPolicy;
import com.android.volley.Request.Method;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.RetryPolicy;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalConfiguration;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalItem;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalPayment;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalPaymentDetails;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentActivity;
import com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentConfirmation;

public class ItemsList extends Activity implements ProductListAdapterListener {
    private static final String TAG = ItemsList.class.getSimpleName();

    private ListView listView;
    private Button btnCheckout;

    // To store all the products
    private List<Product> productsList;

    // To store the products those are added to cart
    private List<PayPalItem> productsInCart = new ArrayList<PayPalItem>();

    private ProductListAdapter adapter;

    // Progress dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT = 1;

    // PayPal configuration
    private static PayPalConfiguration paypalConfig = new PayPalConfiguration()
            .environment(Config.PAYPAL_ENVIRONMENT).clientId(
                    Config.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID);

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.food_menu);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        btnCheckout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.checkout);
        productsList = new ArrayList<Product>();

        adapter = new ProductListAdapter(ItemsList.this, productsList, this);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);

        // Starting PayPal service
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PayPalService.class);
        intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, paypalConfig);
        startService(intent);

        // Checkout button click listener
        btnCheckout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // Check for empty cart
                if (productsInCart.size() > 0) {
                    launchPayPalPayment();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Cart is empty! Please add few products to cart.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });

        // Fetching products from server
        fetchProducts();
    }

    /**
     * Fetching the products from our server
     * */
    private void fetchProducts() {
        // Showing progress dialog before making request

        pDialog.setMessage("Fetching products...");

        showpDialog();

        // Making json object request
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
                Config.URL_PRODUCTS, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                        try {
                            JSONArray products = response
                                    .getJSONArray("products");

                            // looping through all product nodes and storing
                            // them in array list
                            for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject product = (JSONObject) products
                                        .get(i);

                                String id = product.getString("p_id");
                                String name = product.getString("p_name");
                                String description = product
                                        .getString("p_desc");
                                String image = product.getString("p_image");
                                BigDecimal price = new BigDecimal(product
                                        .getString("p_price"));
                                String sku = product.getString("p_status");

                                Product p = new Product(id, name, description,
                                        image, price, sku);

                                productsList.add(p);
                            }
                            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                            // notifying adapter about data changes, so that the
                            // list renders with new data
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                        // hiding the progress dialog
                        hidepDialog();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        // hide the progress dialog
                        hidepDialog();
                    }
                });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
    }

    /**
     * Verifying the mobile payment on the server to avoid fraudulent payment
     * */
    private void verifyPaymentOnServer(final String paymentId,
            final String payment_client) {
        // Showing progress dialog before making request
        pDialog.setMessage("Verifying payment...");
        showpDialog();

        StringRequest verifyReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
                Config.URL_VERIFY_PAYMENT, new Response.Listener<String>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "verify payment: " + response.toString());

                        try {
                            JSONObject res = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean error = res.getBoolean("error");
                            String message = res.getString("message");

                            // user error boolean flag to check for errors

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            if (!error) {
                                // empty the cart
                                productsInCart.clear();
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        // hiding the progress dialog
                        hidepDialog();

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Verify Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        // hiding the progress dialog
                        hidepDialog();
                    }
                }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {

                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("paymentId", paymentId);
                params.put("paymentClientJson", payment_client);

                return params;
            }
        };

        // Setting timeout to volley request as verification request takes
        // sometime
        int socketTimeout = 60000;
        RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
        verifyReq.setRetryPolicy(policy);

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(verifyReq);
    }

    /**
     * Preparing final cart amount that needs to be sent to PayPal for payment
     * */
    private PayPalPayment prepareFinalCart() {

        PayPalItem[] items = new PayPalItem[productsInCart.size()];
        items = productsInCart.toArray(items);

        // Total amount
        BigDecimal subtotal = PayPalItem.getItemTotal(items);

        // If you have shipping cost, add it here
        BigDecimal shipping = new BigDecimal("0.0");

        // If you have tax, add it here
        BigDecimal tax = new BigDecimal("0.0");

        PayPalPaymentDetails paymentDetails = new PayPalPaymentDetails(
                shipping, subtotal, tax);

        BigDecimal amount = subtotal.add(shipping).add(tax);

        PayPalPayment payment = new PayPalPayment(
                amount,
                Config.DEFAULT_CURRENCY,
                "Description about transaction. This will be displayed to the user.",
                Config.PAYMENT_INTENT);

        payment.items(items).paymentDetails(paymentDetails);

        // Custom field like invoice_number etc.,
        payment.custom("This is text that will be associated with the payment that the app can use.");

        return payment;
    }

    /**
     * Launching PalPay payment activity to complete the payment
     * */
    private void launchPayPalPayment() {

        PayPalPayment thingsToBuy = prepareFinalCart();

        Intent intent = new Intent(ItemsList.this, PaymentActivity.class);

        intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, paypalConfig);

        intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, thingsToBuy);

        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT);
    }

    /**
     * Receiving the PalPay payment response
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                PaymentConfirmation confirm = data
                        .getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
                if (confirm != null) {
                    try {
                        Log.e(TAG, confirm.toJSONObject().toString(4));
                        Log.e(TAG, confirm.getPayment().toJSONObject()
                                .toString(4));

                        String paymentId = confirm.toJSONObject()
                                .getJSONObject("response").getString("id");

                        String payment_client = confirm.getPayment()
                                .toJSONObject().toString();

                        Log.e(TAG, "paymentId: " + paymentId
                                + ", payment_json: " + payment_client);

                        // Now verify the payment on the server side
                        verifyPaymentOnServer(paymentId, payment_client);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "an extremely unlikely failure occurred: ",
                                e);
                    }
                }
            } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Log.e(TAG, "The user canceled.");
            } else if (resultCode == PaymentActivity.RESULT_EXTRAS_INVALID) {
                Log.e(TAG,
                        "An invalid Payment or PayPalConfiguration was submitted.");
            }
        }
    }

    private void showpDialog() {
        if (!pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.show();
    }

    private void hidepDialog() {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAddToCartPressed(Product product) {

        PayPalItem item = new PayPalItem(product.getname(), 1,
                product.getprice(), Config.DEFAULT_CURRENCY, product.getsku());

        productsInCart.add(item);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                item.getName() + " added to cart!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Product {
    private String id, name, description, image, sku;
    private BigDecimal price;

    public Product() {

    }
    public Product(String id, String name, String description, String image,
            BigDecimal price, String sku) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.image = image;
        this.price = price;
        this.sku = sku;
    }
    public String getid() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getname() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getdescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public String getimage() {
        return image;
    }
    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
    public BigDecimal getprice() {
        return price;
    }

    public String getsku() {
        return sku;
    }
}

---------------------------------------------------------------
package com.flavorbaba;

import com.flavorbaba.R;
import com.flavorbaba.AppController;


import java.util.List;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView;

public class ProductListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Product> products;
    private ProductListAdapterListener listener;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public ProductListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Product> feedItems,
            ProductListAdapterListener listener) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.products = feedItems;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return products.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return products.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_product, null);

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

        TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.productName);
        TextView description = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.productDescription);
        TextView price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.productPrice);

        NetworkImageView image = (NetworkImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.productImage);

        Button btnAddToCart = (Button) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.btnAddToCart);

        final Product product = products.get(position);

        name.setText(product.getname());

        description.setText(product.getdescription());

        price.setText("Price: $" + product.getprice());

        // user profile pic
        image.setImageUrl(product.getimage(), imageLoader);
        btnAddToCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                listener.onAddToCartPressed(product);
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    public interface ProductListAdapterListener {
        public void onAddToCartPressed(Product product);
    }

}
```

Comment: where is your logcat?

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.flavorbaba/com.flavorbaba.ItemsList}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
   at com.flavorbaba.ItemsList.fetchProducts(ItemsList.java:185)
   at com.flavorbaba.ItemsList.onCreate(ItemsList.java:111)

Comment: at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)

Comment: Add the logcat output to your question. What is line 185?

Answer (score 0):

This is a lot ta code dude...
I Wonder why your Productlistadapter object needs two contexts and why you give the first context as Item activity.this but nevertheless

One big Problem here is that you are trying to make a network connection on the main thread...that's an error when you are in strict mode while debugging...

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can please guide me to rectify it. I am not so much expert in android

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the problem because your log at should tell you a networkonmainthread error but just do it like that     new Thread (new Runnable (){public void run (){fetchItems ();}}).start ();

Comment: I'm at mobile at so basically place the fetch method into a thread but as I said log cat should tell you the true fail and as far as I saw nullpointer was triggered